# Matrix Exponential using hyperbolic rotation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

How can one show that 
$$
\exp(A)=\exp(a)  
\begin{pmatrix}
        \cosh(b) & \sinh(b)\\
        \sinh(b) & \cosh(b)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
if
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\b&a\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
? 
I was trying to rewrite $A$ as 
$$
a*\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\ \end{pmatrix}+b*\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and then I clearly see, that 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}*\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\\ \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
which simplifies the calculations significantly. But I still do not see the big picture. We also proved in the lecture, that 
$$
\exp(A)=\lim\limits_{k\mapsto \infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{A^k}{k!}
$$
Thanks a lot.